# How to save PHP form data to a session variable without updating database in Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, post

I'm building my PHP/MySQL site with Dreamweaver because my skills are fairly minimal and I want to save selections from a multiple option drop-down list to a `$_SESSION` variable.  I have successfully managed to save to the session variables when updating the fields in the database using the following on a previous page and seems to be working (the top of the page inserted by Dreamweaver, I commented where I edited it to make it store to the `$_SESSION`):

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
  function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
  {
    if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
      $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
    }

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

    switch ($theType) {
      case "text":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;    
      case "long":
      case "int":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
        break;
      case "double":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
        break;
      case "date":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;
      case "defined":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
        break;
    }
    return $theValue;
  }
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
/// this is what to edit to make session variables from a form
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "SelectBookForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO characters (character_name1, play_system, character_owner) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['NewCharacterNameInput'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int"));
                       $_SESSION['play_system'] = GetSQLValueString($_POST['select'], "text");
                       $_SESSION['character_owner'] = GetSQLValueString($_POST['CharacterOwner'], "int");
                       $_SESSION['character_name1'] = GetSQLValueString($_POST['NewCharacterNameInput'], "text");

  mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "character_new_book_select.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$login = mysql_query($query_login, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
$totalRows_login = mysql_num_rows($login);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_play_systems_recordset = "SELECT * FROM play_systems";
$play_systems_recordset = mysql_query($query_play_systems_recordset, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset);
$totalRows_play_systems_recordset = mysql_num_rows($play_systems_recordset);

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_CharacterOwner = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.user_id = 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = '{$_SESSION['MM_Username']}')";
$CharacterOwner = mysql_query($query_CharacterOwner, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CharacterOwner = mysql_fetch_assoc($CharacterOwner);
$totalRows_CharacterOwner = mysql_num_rows($CharacterOwner);
?>
```

This is what Dreamweaver uses to make the form in the body of the page (again, this is the one that's working):

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="SelectBookForm" method="POST" id="SelectBookForm"> 
  <select name="select" size="1" form="SelectBookForm">
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system']?>"><?php echo $row_play_systems_recordset['play_system']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($play_systems_recordset);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($play_systems_recordset, 0);
      $row_play_systems_recordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($play_systems_recordset);
  }
?>
  </select>
  <input name="CharacterOwner" type="hidden" id="CharacterOwner" value="<?php echo $row_CharacterOwner['user_id']; ?>"><input name="NewCharacterNameInput" type="text" required id="NewCharacterNameInput" form="SelectBookForm" placeholder="Give your character a name!" size="25" maxlength="128">
      <BR>
  <input name="NewCharacterSubmit" type="submit" id="NewCharacterSubmit" form="SelectBookForm" value="Select system and start my character">

      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="PlaySystemForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="SelectBookForm">
</form>
```

There doesn't seem to be an option to just save to the `$_SESSION` rather than input or update to the database in Dreamweaver.  Every time I try to even create the recordset I get an error on line 114 which is just a blank space between two `}` brackets.

This is the form of the page I'm trying to create:

```
<form method="post" id="BookSelectionForm">
<select name="BookSelections" size="10" multiple id="BookSelections" form="BookSelectionForm">
  <?php
do {  
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['book']?>"><?php echo $row_BooksRecordset['book']?></option>
  <?php
} while ($row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($BooksRecordset, 0);
      $row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
  }
?>
</select>

<input name="BookSelectionFormSubmitButton" type="submit" id="BookSelectionFormSubmitButton" form="BookSelectionForm" formmethod="POST" value="Select these campaigns">
</form>
```

It works and is restricting the data exactly how it should, based on the input from the example at the top of this post.  Long story short, I want to store the selections from the multiple option drop-down list as a `$_SESSION['book']` variable so I can use it on the next page.  Can someone help put me on the correct course to achieve this?

Not sure how much value it is, but here is also the top of the page recordset information Dreamweaver is allowing without an error.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
  function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
  {
    if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
      $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
    }

    $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

    switch ($theType) {
      case "text":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;    
      case "long":
      case "int":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
        break;
      case "double":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
        break;
      case "date":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
        break;
      case "defined":
        $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
        break;
    }
    return $theValue;
  }


}

mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$login = mysql_query($query_login, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
$totalRows_login = mysql_num_rows($login);

/// this one sets the play_system to the one selected at the beginning and can be used to restrict results by using the variable $BooksRecordset, I probably need to change this because it's confusing.  It's giving the play_system and not the books.  Maybe RealBooksRecordset is better for now.
mysql_select_db($database_DLP_RPG, $DLP_RPG);
$query_BooksRecordset = "SELECT * FROM character_system WHERE character_system.system_name = ({$_SESSION['play_system']})";
$BooksRecordset = mysql_query($query_BooksRecordset, $DLP_RPG) or die(mysql_error());
$row_BooksRecordset = mysql_fetch_assoc($BooksRecordset);
$totalRows_BooksRecordset = mysql_num_rows($BooksRecordset);



?>
```

EDIT: I figured out why I got the error on line 114 as it was an errant bracket, still having trouble getting it to add recordsets, though.

Comment: have you write `session_start()` at the top of your page??

Comment: Yes, the session is working, I tried to put the minimum code because I ran out of room and had too many characters on previous posts.  The page loads and the drop-down list is restricting data properly using Session variables.  I want to post to a new session variable.

Comment: use a framwork, for example: laravel

Comment: I don't think I have the permissions on my host to be able to install that kind of package, but I will look into it.  Looking at the website, the use of that framework may be just beyond where I'm at, skill-wise.

Answer (score 6):

(The first time I read this post I thought it was a joke. Then I glanced over some of your answers and **I get the feeling you're a victim of SO coderot,** for which you can't be blamed. It's entirely too easy to Google your way to garbage about PHP.)

> Long story short, I want to store the selections from the multiple option drop-down list as a $_SESSION['book'] variable so I can use it on the next page. **Can someone help put me on the correct course to achieve this?**

Sure. So, first off: telling a bunch of programmers that you're using Dreamweaver to write PHP because you lack skill is like telling a group of hunters that you're going after a bear with a sling shot because you don't know how to shoot a gun: expect lots of advice about shooting guns or hunting rabbits, but don't expect much help with the slingshot.

tl;dr: Dreamweaver is not helping you. It is part of the reason you're struggling just to get answers.

- You're looking for [*serializing*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [***Please stop using that mysql library***](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)
- ...and this?

  ```
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) { 
      $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }
  ```

[ಠ_ಠ](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

Just fyi, the biggest reason you're having trouble getting it to add the record sets because that approach hasn't been reasonable in over a decade. At least [use something actually supported](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Hope that gets you point in the right direction. I'm around if you need more help.

Comment: I know I'm eventually going to have to move to mysqli or one of the other methods of connecting to the database, but what's on the page is what Dreamweaver puts in with its "Server behaviors".  This page isn't going to store any valuable data, it's just to act as a proof of concept so I can show potential developers and get some estimates for the work.  I'll look into serializing and try to figure out how to apply it to the output I need.  Otherwise I'll come up with some kind of workaround that posts data to the table so I can get the $_SESSION I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoeCook You do realize that the expectation of having to completely refactor your _proof of concept_ would increase my time estimate by half again at least, right? Yes, I know what Dreamweaver-domain server-side generated code looks like, and I know how much of a time sink it is to be given a PoC from somebody who stridently insists I actually need it (protip: I don't) when there's a very good chance he really just wants to see his code deployed to a production environment and needs my help "making it work." (You can tell by how hard he resists sage advice, especially to refactor. ;) )

Comment: I think the part you might be missing is that `serialize` pairs with `unserialize`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php. You can call `serialize` to put the values in a $_SESSION variable in the response, and then in the next request you can use `unserialize` to pull them back out into code.

Comment: @JoeCook Misandrist's point is that _I did answer your question_, all you had to do was try. At all. The only thing that separates your question from a request for free work on Stack (and thus getting moderated, fyi) is the part where you asked to be pointed in the right direction.* You got pointed in the right direction.

Comment: My thanks for the help and my looking into serialization as suggested was delivered without sarcasm.  I do not know why it was removed or appears to incite such anger.  Answering the question at the top is that it won't allow me through DW to save from a button to a variable.  I'm still trying to figure out what happens when the button is pressed by the user, but it looks like it has something to do with $editFormAction.  I am going to try removing the connection to the server from the action and having it just set the variable.  I think I can put the serialize command somewhere in there.